# Filter rows of a table based on a condition that implies: 1) value of a field within a range 2) id of the business and 3) date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to filter a TableA, taking into account only those rows whose "TotalInvoice" field is within the minimum and maximum values expressed in a ViewB, based on month and year values and RepairShopId (the sample data only has one RepairShopId, but all the data has multiple IDs).

In the view I have minimum and maximum values for each business and each month and year.

TableA

| RepairOrderDataId | RepairShopId | LastUpdated | TotalInvoice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2017-06-01 07:00:00.000 | 765 |
| 1 | 10 | 2017-06-05 12:15:00.000 | 765 |
| 2 | 10 | 2017-02-25 13:00:00.000 | 400 |
| 3 | 10 | 2017-10-19 12:15:00.000 | 295679 |
| 4 | 10 | 2016-11-29 11:00:00.000 | 133409.41 |
| 5 | 10 | 2016-10-28 12:30:00.000 | 127769 |
| 6 | 10 | 2016-11-25 16:15:00.000 | 122400 |
| 7 | 10 | 2016-10-18 11:15:00.000 | 1950 |
| 8 | 10 | 2016-11-07 16:45:00.000 | 79342.7 |
| 9 | 10 | 2016-11-25 19:15:00.000 | 1950 |
| 10 | 10 | 2016-12-09 14:00:00.000 | 111559 |
| 11 | 10 | 2016-11-28 10:30:00.000 | 106333 |
| 12 | 10 | 2016-12-13 18:00:00.000 | 23847.4 |
| 13 | 10 | 2016-11-01 17:00:00.000 | 22782.9 |
| 14 | 10 | 2016-10-07 15:30:00.000 | NULL |
| 15 | 10 | 2017-01-06 15:30:00.000 | 138958 |
| 16 | 10 | 2017-01-31 13:00:00.000 | 244484 |
| 17 | 10 | 2016-12-05 09:30:00.000 | 180236 |
| 18 | 10 | 2017-02-14 18:30:00.000 | 92752.6 |
| 19 | 10 | 2016-10-05 08:30:00.000 | 161952 |
| 20 | 10 | 2016-10-05 08:30:00.000 | 8713.08 |

ViewB

| RepairShopId | Orders | Average | MinimumValue | MaximumValue | year | month | yearMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 370343 | 370343 | 370343 | 2015 | 7 | 2015-7 |
| 10 | 1 | 109645 | 109645 | 109645 | 2015 | 10 | 2015-10 |
| 10 | 1 | 148487 | 148487 | 148487 | 2015 | 12 | 2015-12 |
| 10 | 1 | 133409.41 | 133409.41 | 133409.41 | 2016 | 3 | 2016-3 |
| 10 | 1 | 19261 | 19261 | 19261 | 2016 | 8 | 2016-8 |
| 10 | 4 | 10477.3575 | 2656.65644879821 | 18298.0585512018 | 2016 | 9 | 2016-9 |
| 10 | 69 | 15047.709565 | 10 | 90942.6052417394 | 2016 | 10 | 2016-10 |
| 10 | 98 | 22312.077244 | 10 | 147265.581935242 | 2016 | 11 | 2016-11 |
| 10 | 96 | 20068.147395 | 10 | 99974.1750708773 | 2016 | 12 | 2016-12 |
| 10 | 86 | 25334.053372 | 10 | 184186.985160105 | 2017 | 1 | 2017-1 |
| 10 | 69 | 21410.63855 | 10 | 153417.00126689 | 2017 | 2 | 2017-2 |
| 10 | 100 | 13009.797 | 10 | 59002.3589332934 | 2017 | 3 | 2017-3 |
| 10 | 101 | 11746.191287 | 10 | 71405.3391452842 | 2017 | 4 | 2017-4 |
| 10 | 123 | 11143.49756 | 10 | 55306.8202091131 | 2017 | 5 | 2017-5 |
| 10 | 197 | 15980.55406 | 10 | 204538.144334771 | 2017 | 6 | 2017-6 |
| 10 | 99 | 10852.496969 | 10 | 63283.9899761938 | 2017 | 7 | 2017-7 |
| 10 | 131 | 52601.981526 | 10 | 1314998.61355187 | 2017 | 8 | 2017-8 |
| 10 | 124 | 10983.221854 | 10 | 59444.0535811233 | 2017 | 9 | 2017-9 |
| 10 | 115 | 12467.148434 | 10 | 72996.6054527277 | 2017 | 10 | 2017-10 |
| 10 | 123 | 14843.379593 | 10 | 129673.931373139 | 2017 | 11 | 2017-11 |
| 10 | 111 | 8535.455945 | 10 | 50328.1495501884 | 2017 | 12 | 2017-12 |

I've tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN ViewB ON TableA.RepairShopId = ViewB.RepairShopId
WHERE TotalInvoice > MinimumValue AND TotalInvoice < MaximumValue
AND TableA.RepairShopId = ViewB.RepairShopId
```

But I'm not sure how to compare it the yearMonth field with the datetime field "LastUpdated".

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: I've tried:

SELECT * FROM TableA 
WHERE TotalInvoice > MinimumValue AND TotalInvoice 
 < MaximumValue
AND TableA.RepairShopId = ViewB.RepairShopId

Comment: And we need to see your desired results.

Comment: I assumed you meant to join ViewB in your query... if not edit it out. Also we need to see your desired results. And if you provide sample data as DDL+DML I'd have a look, but I'm not typing it all in.

Comment: Maybe DATEFROMPARTS will help e.g. `LastUpdated >= DATEFROMPARTS ( year, month, 1 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you can do it:
I assumed LastUpdated column is the column from tableA which indicate date of

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN ViewB B
ON A.RepairShopId = B.RepairShopId
AND A.TotalInvoice > B.MinimumValue 
AND A.TotalInvoice < B.MaximumValue
AND YEAR(LastUpdated) = B.year
AND MONTH(LastUpdated) = B.month
```